# Average power dissipated by a diode

Tags: power, diodes, rms, bootstrap

EDIT: Added a picture with values and a better explanation.

I need a little help over this calculation.

I have to calculate the average power dissipated by a bootstrap diode (actually a MOSFET connected as a diode) in a buck converter.

We know that \$P_{avg}= \int_{0}^{T_{SW}}p(t)dt\$

Since I have the instantaneous voltage across the diode (red) and the instantaneous current across the diode (yellow,) I can obtain the instantaneous power (green.)

Now to calculate the average power in a period just sum the area of the 4 blue triangles, right?

Doubt arises from the fact that by using \$ P_{avg}=V_{rms}I_{rms}\$ , I obtain an 8 times higher value than the one calculated with the triangles' area.  It seems that this formula cannot be used in this case

Many questions online referr to sine waves or in the case of the diode the answer is typically "use \$ P_{avg}=R_{D}I^{2}_{rms}\$ for conduction losses and then calculate reverse recovery losses with the triangle area" but I don't have \$ R_{D}\$ and I prefer to work over these waveforms.

[image]

Comment: I assume that the small triangle in the lower left corner is the origin of the axis, in that case you have to account the whole area bellow the curve (eg. bellow the "straight" parts)

Comment: If you multiply red and yellow line, you won't get the green as from yours calculation. Also, it can't be negative because the diode certainly can't be cooler than air, since it can't work as refrigerator.

Comment: At a first glance, i would say, that the power would be something like this: https://imgur.com/a/Pjxx7Me

Comment: Why would you  use AVG=RMS\*RMS? AVG=average(instantaneous\*instantaneous). In other words, the definite integral over one cycle of v(t) and i(t). Plot v(t)\*i(t) over one cycle and perform an average.

Comment: @MarekCoufal Updated the picure vith current and voltage values, shouldn't be a big problem (it isn't by having no time reference) 
When there's the big peak the diode start conducting and then acts as a short circuit (voltage almost zero),when the bootstrap is in action the voltage across the diode drops to battery attached 
Current goes negative due to reverse recovery
Green wave is literally the product between red and yellow made in simulator

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen you are right but first i should take the absolute value of the green wave because by averaging you find a smaller value compared to triangles area sum...power goes negative due to negative current but in fact it sums up

Comment: @KiDMiO No real power average will be smaller than, or even equal to zero, because the efficiency is always less than 100%. That means you don't have to take the absolute value, as the formula clearly shows: \$P=\int_0^T{v(t)i(t)\mathrm{d}t\$. The *instantaneous* value may go negative, but the *average* never will. If it does, you're plotting a negative quantity, i.e. -i(t), instead of i(t), or the program/schematic has have numerical issues, or the models have internal sources.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen yes by calculating the average of p(t) i obtain a positive value around 12e-3 for one period...thanks very much!